# R - Looking for a better syntax in a dplyr::mutate/if_else combination

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a question on the conditional creation of a new column using `dplyr::mutate`, using `ifelse`/`if_else`

I will use the iris dataset as an example. First I define a general setting

```
setting1 = TRUE; # general setting
```

I want to create a new column based on the value of another (here the Sepal.Length)
but with a different formula depending of the boolean setting1 value.
My first move was (following some example found somewhere, I'm quite a newbie in R):

```
iris2 <- iris %>% slice_head(n=5) %>%
  mutate( NewSL = ifelse(setting1, Sepal.Length*10., Sepal.Length/10.) )
```

But there is an issue in the value calculated, which appears to be the
value of the first line which is propagated

```
iris2
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species NewSL
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    51
 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    51
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    51
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    51
 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa    51
```

I understood then it was due to a problem of length, which is clearly
identified when I replace ifelse by if_else

```
iris2 <- iris %>% slice_head(n=5) %>%
  mutate( NewSL = if_else(setting1, Sepal.Length*10., Sepal.Length/10.) )
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `NewSL`.
> i `NewSL = if_else(setting1, Sepal.Length * 10, Sepal.Length/10)`.
> x `true` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 5.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I can do this ugly thing to make it work

```
rm(iris2)
iris2 <- iris %>% slice_head(n=5) %>%
  mutate( NewSL = if_else( rep(setting1, n()), Sepal.Length*10., Sepal.Length/10.) )
```

and if fact in my real case the false part is a constant so I have to do that twice

```
iris2 <- iris %>% slice_head(n=5) %>%
  mutate( NewSL = if_else( rep(setting1, n()), Sepal.Length*10., rep(10.0, n()) ) )
```

My question is: **Is there an elegant/concise tidy-like way to make this work properly work withoout the rep() trick?**

Most examples of the mutate/if_else combination use a column of the dataset in the condition part,
not a constant, so no issue with lengths in this case

Of note, I also managed to have the correct output using other approaches

1. either using  R base syntax

```
iris2 <- iris
if (setting1) {
  iris2$NewSL=  iris2$Sepal.Length*10.
} else {
  iris2$NewSL = iris2$Sepal.Length/10.
  # or iris2$NewSL = 10.0
}
```

2. or using conditional piping to stay in the tidyverse syntax, which seems to work correctly, but I found also quite verbose and less readable for a such simple case

```
iris2 <- iris %>% slice_head(n=5) %>%
  {if(setting1) mutate(., NewSL = Sepal.Length*10.) 
    else mutate(., NewSL = Sepal.Length/10.) }
```

I'd like to know the most efficient way to do it properly, using the tidyverse syntax.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelse`/`if_else` are for vectors. You should continue using `if` as you have already identified.

```
library(dplyr)

setting1 = TRUE

iris %>% 
  slice_head(n=5) %>%
  mutate( NewSL = if(setting1) Sepal.Length*10 else Sepal.Length/10)

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species NewSL
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    51
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    49
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    47
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    46
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa    50
```

Comment: So simple, I'm feeling a little dumb. I didn't find examples with classical if structure inside a mutate line when I looked for answers (in the conditional piping, the if is outside the mutate call), and I thought everything was vectorized in dplyr. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In my real world case, I in fact use more than one operation on the column. My initial code was something like
`Sepal.Length * if_else(setting1, ... )  / if_else(setting2,...) / if_else(setting3,...)`
Is it possible to have nested if ...  else inside a mutate, to extend your answer? or is it limited to one if .. else? In this case I will have to create multiple calls to mutate I guess, one per condition

Comment: Sorry, your comment is not clear to me. But you can have nested `if`/`else` statements `if(setting1) {..} else if(setting2) {...}`. You can also combine two conditions using `&`/`&&` `if(setting1 && setting2) {...}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I expected the { } might be possible to nest if, but was not sure. And sorry for the unclear example, the slash / was indeed confusing: it was a division sign, the example would have been clearer with only multiplication
`Sepal.Length * if_else(setting1, ... ) * if_else(setting2,...) * if_else(setting3,...)`